# "Striscindovisi": quale verbo è e cosa significa?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Con gli occhi chiusi* di Federigo Tozzi  ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Nelle ore di caldo asfissiante, quando la trattoria restava vuota, lo sguattero e il cuoco dormivano con il capo appoggiato sopra il ceppo, coprendosi con i loro grembiuli per via delle mosche che volavano su gli strofinacci untuosi; si fermavano, tutte accosto, intorno ad una goccia di brodo rimasta sopra la tavola; camminavano in su e in giù sopra i pezzi della carne, **striscindovisi** sopra. La marmittona di rame seguitava a bollire; un gatto, sotto la tavola, rosicchiava. Una cannella d'ottone, mal chiusa, sgocciolava con un sibilo incessante. Le due zangole battevano, sopra una parete, i riflessi trasparenti della loro acqua; che, di quando in quando, erano attraversati dall'ombra di una mosca.

La mia domanda è su questo "striscindovisi" che appare nel brano sopra citato. Di quale verbo si tratta? "Striscire"? "Striscirsi"? Non ho trovato tali vocaboli su nessun dizionario, inclusi il Treccani e il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* (GDLI).

E cosa significa? Magari "strisciarsi" (sui pezzi di carne)?

Devo dire che molti dei termini che appaiono su questo libro li ho trovati soltanto sul GDLI, che cita nelle voci corrispondenti molti esempi di Tozzi, tra i quali molti di questo romanzo. Aggiungo anche che si tratta di un testo con molti toscanismi.

Comment: Questa edizione riporta “strisciandovisi sopra”. https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Pagina:Con_gli_occhi_chiusi.djvu/137 - direi che “striscindovisi” è un typo.

Comment: Anche qui:https://books.google.it/books?id=8eKtyLHUfgIC&pg=PT61&lpg=PT61&dq=Nelle+ore+di+caldo+asfissiante,+quando+la+trattoria+restava+vuota,+lo+sguattero+e+il+cuoco+dormivano+con+il+capo+appoggiato+sopra+il+ceppo,+coprendosi+con+i+loro+grembiuli+per+via+delle+mosche+che+volavano+su+gli+strofinacci+untuosi;+si+fermavano,+tutte+accosto,+intorno+ad+una+goccia+di+brodo+rimasta+sopra+la+tavola;+camminavano+in+su+e+in+gi%C3%B9+sopra+i+pezzi+della+carne,&source=bl&ots=6Yx0NsTEA0&sig=ACfU3U3WzFCqO88z65VTzexc-E3F9enFvg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtqeu85untAhUa6OAKHafOAioQ6AEwA3oECAwQAQ#v=snippet&q&f=false

Comment: E qui: https://books.google.it/books?id=z8rpIFHUmQMC&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=Nelle+ore+di+caldo+asfissiante,+quando+la+trattoria+restava+vuota,+lo+sguattero+e+il+cuoco+dormivano+con+il+capo+appoggiato+sopra+il+ceppo,+coprendosi+con+i+loro+grembiuli+per+via+delle+mosche+che+volavano+su+gli+strofinacci+untuosi;+si+fermavano,+tutte+accosto,+intorno+ad+una+goccia+di+brodo+rimasta+sopra+la+tavola;+camminavano+in+su+e&source=bl&ots=6syfTsod4K&sig=ACfU3U03lm3MTpf_vps0IrPwrbbRtMJu0Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2-_Ou7untAhWBD2MBHYh7Az0Q6AEwBHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Ah, grazie, @Hachi! Allora si dovrebbe chiudere la domanda come off-topic.

Comment: Voto per chiudere questa domanda perché non si tratta di una questione d'italiano, ma di tipografia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A me di primo istinto verrebbe da dire che è un errore di stampa per *strisci**a**ndovisi*.

Comment: Mmmm... Può darsi che sia così... La cosa curiosa è che, a quanto pare, edizioni diverse hanno "striscindovisi". Per esempio, ho trovato [questo](https://books.google.es/books?id=I8DceUYYuesC&pg=PT170&lpg=PT170&dq=striscindovisi&source=bl&ots=5EAi_uzpBE&sig=ACfU3U1t52rhIVQlU5N78jJaeJhCReb5lA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5v6yLsentAhUpD2MBHbHBCQsQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=striscindovisi&f=false), che non corrisponde alla stessa casa editrice che ho io.